# how to replace blank space with "_" on every element's list - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace

I imported a .csv file with this command:

```
 mydata = pd.read_csv(file ,sep='\t' , engine='python' , dtype = {'Day' : np.datetime64 , 'Year' : np.int}  )
```

But i noticed than some of the column name has blank spaces like `Account id` instead of `Account_id`

Now i got the list of my columns name with this:

```
dwb_col= data.columns
```

And i'd like to replace `blank spaces " "` with `"_"` sign on every column name (i.e. every dwb_col element).

in order to rename the columns in this way:
mydata.columns = [my_new_columns_list]

1. **How i can do the find and replace part?**
2. **Is there any workaround/shortcut during the importing fase that let me collect the column name with "_"(underscore sign) over the "
       " (space)** ?

Comment: Could you add some dummy data? Are you importing multiple csv's and some of them have different column names?

Comment: i'm loading just one csv file which has some columns named like this: 'column 1' instead of 'column_1'.

Comment: data.columns = [x.replace(' ', '_') for x in data.columns]

Comment: no.2 wasn't clear I wasn't sure if you wanted to only gather column names with `'_'` or do the replacement in the read argument, either way any of the solutions below will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way would be using regex `\s+` which will match 1 or more white spaces whilst `' '` will only match one

```
dwb_col = df.columns.str.replace('\s+', '_')
```

then just re-assign

```
df.columns = dwb_col
```

if you have trailing or leading white space you want to remove first you can add a
`str.strip`

```
df.columns.str.strip().str.replace('\s+', '_')
```

regarding number 2 you can import your file and use the `nrows` argument to only collect the top n rows to gather the column names.

```
col_df = pd.read_csv(data,nrows=1)
cols = [col for col in col_df.columns.tolist() if '_' in col]
```

then read your data with `usecols`

```
df = pd.read_csv(data,usecols=cols)
```

Answer (score 6):

This will do, using `str.replace`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(" ", "_")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,assume your column names are like this

```
l = ["hello world","hello cat"]
cols = ['_'.join(i.split()) for i in l]
#outout
['hello_world', 'hello_cat']
```